# javascript - check at least one radio button is selected on the page

Tags: javascript, html, radio-button

i am trying to check that at least one of my radio buttons are checked on the page, they are in different groups so i have tried to create an aray of all the groups and run therough them but i cant seems to see what is wrong with the code anyone know what i am doing wrong ?

```
function atLeastOneRadio() { 
      var chx = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
      var day = new array();
      day[0] = "monday";
      day[1] = "tuesday";
      day[2] = "wednesday";
      day[3] = "thursday";
      day[4] = "friday";
      for (var i=0; i<chx.length; i++) {
        if (chx[i].type == 'radio' chx[i].name == day[i] && chx[i].checked) {
          return true;
        } 
      }
      return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have jQuery it might be a bit shorter.

Something like:

```
//returns number of elements checked
$("input:checked").size();


//if you need to check if the name of the element is equal to something
$("input:checked").each(function(i){
    return($.inArray(this.name, days));
});
```

Comment: Could you talk me through what it is actualy doing as I am new to jquery

Comment: the $('input') gets all the inputs on the page.  The ':checked' filters all of those inputs to only return the checked ones.  .each will loop through all of the checked inputs returned by the selector.  Then inArray is a just a helper to check if a object is in an array.  http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/

Comment: Thank you , So would this return true if there is at least one radio button checked on the page?

Comment: I updated the answer a bit. You can just use size if you want to know if any input is check.  You will have to loop through with .each if you need to check the names.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (var i=0; i<chx.length; i++) {
   for (var x=0; x< day.length;x++) {
        if (chx[i].type == 'radio' chx[i].name == day[x] && chx[i].checked) {
          return true;
        } 
    }
}
```