# How to check if at least one radio button is checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, radio-button

I'm actually stuck on my form validation because I want to check if there is at least one radio button checked. I did this for my text input validation successful but for the radio buttons it doesn't work.

```js
$('#next').click(function() {
    var isValid = true;
    $('.personal-informations, .gender, .goal').each(function(i, obj) { //.personal-informations are my text inputs in another section of my form and .gender and .goal are my radio button classes
        if ($(this).val().trim() === '') {
            $("html, body").animate({scrollTop: $('.progressbar-header').offset().top-100}, 250);
            $(this).closest('.questions').find('.error').css("visibility","visible");
            $(this).css('border-color', "#B33C3D");
            $(this).closest('.questions').find('.error').text('Dies ist ein Pflichtfeld.');
            isValid = false;
        }
        if ($(this).is(':checked').length > 0) {
        } else {
            $(this).closest('.questions').find('.error').css("visibility","visible");
            $(this).closest('.questions').find('.error').text('This field is required.');
            isValid = false;
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<div class="field goals-icon goals">
    <span class="title">Some Text</span>
    <div class="questions">
        <div class="questions-fc-1 questions-fcm-2 radio-button">
            <input id="muscle-goal_1" name="goal" class="goal" value="1" aria-required="true" type="radio">
            <label id="fc-goal_1" aria-controls="#muscle-goal_1">
                <img src="" alt="">
                <span>Some Text</span>
                    <div class="error"></div><!--This is my error class which should be visible if there is no checkbox from this section checked-->
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="questions-fc-1 questions-fcm-2 radio-button">
            <input id="weight-loss-goal_2" name="goal" class="goal" value="2" aria-required="true" type="radio">
            <label id="fc-goal_2" aria-controls="#weight-loss-goal_2">
                <img src="" alt="">
                <span>Some Text</span>
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="questions-fc-1 questions-fcm-2 radio-button">
            <input id="figure-workout-goal_3" name="goal" class="goal" value="3" aria-required="true" type="radio">
            <label id="fc-goal_3" aria-controls="#figure-workout-goal_3">
                <img src="" alt="">
                <span>Some Text</span>
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="questions-fc-1 questions-fcm-2 radio-button">
            <input id="health-goal_4" name="goal" class="goal" value="4" aria-required="true" type="radio">
            <label id="fc-goal_4" aria-controls="#health-goal_4">
                <img src="" alt="">
                <span>Some Text</span>
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div type="next" id="next" class="forward-button"></div>
```

Comment: if this is a direct copy of your code.. you misspelled `length` in the line `if ($(this).is(':checked').lenght > 0)`

Comment: Could you be more specific? Do you get any errors, what have you tried, where it messes up... This is too localized, and this wouldn't help anyone else.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [javascript - check at least one radio button is selected on the page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14667947/javascript-check-at-least-one-radio-button-is-selected-on-the-page)

Comment: @BviLLe_Kid Tahnk you! I've tried it but nothing happends

Comment: @TheGenieOfTruth No, I don't get any errors :/ I've debugged it and it goes through but it looks like he did this again and again because of the loop? I dont know...

Comment: does nothing happen because you don't have anything inside of your conditional statement?  `if ($(this).is(':checked').length > 0) {
      }` then you go straight to your else statement

Comment: are you sure that the right information is being processed?  What I mean is, are you sure that the `length` is greater than 0? why don't you assign the `length` to a variable and then alert/log it so you can see what is being stored?

Comment: I think I have to make a break... work about 15 hours is too much I think xD I've did it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.is()` returns true, false, or undefined, so checking for truth without the `.length` works. Also you need to re-factor that conditional to traverse up the dom tree to the container (or form), then look for siblings within that.

Replace this:
`if ($(this).is(':checked').length > 0) {`

With this:
`if ($(this).parents('.questions').find('input[type="radio"]').is(':checked')) {`

Based on your example, I'm not sure if you need to tweak the `.parents()` or `.find()` selectors. You may need to make them more specific to stick to the groups of radios (rather than finding all radios). Here is a demo, look at the console and it will log validate fails: https://jsfiddle.net/jpnaccn3/